# Is there a race condition when manually put process into sleep

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, sleep, race-condition, device-driver

When I read ldd3 chapter 6, I was confused by the codes which is shown below:

```
while (spacefree(dev) == 0) { /* full */ DEFINE_WAIT(wait);
    up(&dev->sem);
    if (filp->f_flags & O_NONBLOCK)
        return -EAGAIN;

    PDEBUG("\"%s\" writing: going to sleep\n",current->comm);
    prepare_to_wait(&dev->outq, &wait, TASK_INTERRUPTIBLE);
    if (spacefree(dev) == 0)
        schedule( );
    finish_wait(&dev->outq, &wait);
    if (signal_pending(current))
        return -ERESTARTSYS; /* signal: tell the fs layer to handle it */
    if (down_interruptible(&dev->sem))
        return -ERESTARTSYS;
}
```

Isn't there a race condition between the `if (spacefree(dev) == 0)` and `schedule()`. If the `spacefree(dev)` function returns non-zero when the if statement just finished, maybe the process will lost the only chance to be wake up. Can anyone tell me what is the mechanism behind these codes?

---

By the way, I found another code snippet in *Linux Kernel Development* which is similar to the one above. Some details, however, is different.

```
DEFINE_WAIT(wait);
add_wait_queue(q, &wait);
while (!condition) { /* condition is the event that we are waiting for */
    prepare_to_wait(&q, &wait, TASK_INTERRUPTIBLE);
    if (signal_pending(current))
        /* handle signal */
    schedule();
}
finish_wait(&q, &wait);
```

The very difference is the addition of `add_wait_queue()` function which doesn't appear in the first code snippet.

The second difference is that in the second snippet's `while` statement, there is no condition test before `schedule()`. Why?

The third difference is the position of `signal_pending()` function, one is before the `schedule()`, another is after.

Why there exists such differences?

Answer (score 2):

From LDD3 chapter 6:

*"By checking our condition after setting the process state, we are covered against all
possible sequences of events. If the condition we are waiting for had come about
before setting the process state, we notice in this check and not actually sleep. If the
wakeup happens thereafter, the process is made runnable whether or not we have
actually gone to sleep yet."*